# LDAP Search in Java APP

Tags: java, apache, authentication, ldap, apacheds

I am using this [LDAP class](http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/jldap/jldapenu/api/com/novell/ldap/LDAPConnection.html) in my app.
I have Apache DS at my localhost and it works correctly.

In my app I'm successfully connected to LDAP server:

```
  conn.connect("localhost", 10389);
  conn.bind(LDAPConnection.LDAP_V3, "uid=admin,ou=system","secret".getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Then Im trying to search some data in LDAP catalog:

```
  attrList = new String[]{"dn", "cn", "mail"};
  sFilter = "(mail=admin@test.com)";

  LDAPSearchConstraints cons = new LDAPSearchConstraints();
  cons.setDereference(LDAPSearchConstraints.DEREF_ALWAYS);
  LDAPSearchResults searchResults = conn.search("uid=admin,ou=system", LDAPConnection.SCOPE_SUB, sFilter, attrList, false,cons);
```

And there is no results in searchResults. So can you help me?
But when i user search with SAME PARAMETERS in Apache DS Studio I can see some results.
Please check this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/856brsu13dyjio4/LDAP_V2.png).

Comment: In the screen shot, the filter is different, as is the list of requested attributes. Is that by design?

Comment: Its just my stupid mistake. Screenshot is fixed now.

Comment: Are objects with the `mail` attribute subordinate to `uid=admin,ou=system`? With the base object set to that value, the LDAP directory server will only consider objects at or below the base object as candidates to return to the LDAP client in the search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use code like this:

```
Attributes matchAttrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
matchAttrs.put(new BasiAttribute("mail", "admin@test.com"));
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(context, matchAttrs);
```

Where `ctx` is of type `InitialDirContext`, and `context` is the search root (a context).

Comment: Thanks, but i am using norvell implementation of LDAP.
The root of the issue - incorrect catalog LDAP config